# Google hangout app and separate hangout sessions

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-hangouts

1-2 weeks ago Google Calendar API stopped to create (and return in response) Hangout Url.

People already started to report this problem

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-calendar-api/gNWhbXICZzM
- https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/google-calendar-api#!topic/google-calendar-api/sQT-RwbmZes
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844484/creating-event-with-google-calendar-api-stopped-to-create-hangout-link

We need option to create Hangout session for each event we create.
Does anybody has experience with this and maybe know workaround to create hangout sessions through API (Hangout API or Calendar API)?

**UPDATE**: Creating hangout for events via API works actually but only for default calendar for that account. For any other calendar of that account it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this happening for one specific domain or for multiple? Do you use a service account or Oauth user tokens to authenticate?

Comment: It is happening on single domain and we are using service account.

Comment: @AndrejKaurin: Did you got the Hangout Url from the response? I am also facing the same issue. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

In the Calendar you want to use to create hangout entries, go to the Settings page under the cog icon on the top right, and enable automatic hangout creation.